# Fake order received in magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2

I received the order which has some script in the name fields, it seems to be fake order but how he can place this? Is there any way to stop this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is one of known attack to Magento stores. Until Magento 2.4.3 the attacker can place order using API without any issues. This is usually possible when store owner provide offline payment methods.

How to solve the issue:

1. Upgrade to 2.4.3 and enable ReCaptcha for order place
2. Implement ReCaptcha for Order place for your codebase. I had some experience to implement recaptcha logic for 2.4.1 as temporary solution and it helps.

In both cases this will take some time to implement.